# Getting Unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

trying to make a file that opens an existing text file and looks for a line number in that file. If the line number is not there I want it to print out a message that says that it is not in there.
This is what i have so far. And i am getting the Unexpected EOF error message. Where am I missing the problem?

```
#    Get Input from user
file_name = input("Name of file to open please: ")
try:
    in_file=open(file_name)
    while True:
        find_line = input("Which line number are you looking for? ")
        try:
            line_num=int(find_line)
            line_count=1
            for line_num in in_file:
                if line_count== find_line:
                    print("Line number {} of the file {}, reads: {}".format(find_line,file_name,line_num))
                    break
                line_count+=1
            else:
                print("Line number {} in file {} seems to be missing".format(find_line,file_name))
                in_file.close()
                in_file.open(file_name)
                continue
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("The Line Number you entered",find_line,"is not a correct line number")
            in_file.close()
        except IOError:
            print ("Not sure how to break this to you, but the file your requested",file_str,"well, it's just not there")
    print ("end of program")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is to be expected.  Your **first** try block doesn't have an except block.

```
try:
   # Your code goes here
except:
   print("Error")
```

Comment: Ahh, you should clarify that it is in fact the FIRST try statement that doesn't have a matching except block